# Android 5.0: Issue with setSpan in TextView

Tags: android, textview, android-5.0-lollipop, spannable, imagespan

I'm trying to implement WordCap in a TextView on Android, here is my code:

```
SpannableStringBuilder span = new SpannableStringBuilder();         
span.append(" ");
span.append(str);   
Drawable localDrawable = tvText.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.none);
localDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 105, 1);
ImageSpan isp = new ImageSpan(localDrawable);           
span.setSpan(isp, 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
tvText.setText(span);
```

Result:

[image]

It works fine until I upgrade to Android 5.0 (Lollipop). The drawable setBound is not working anymore. It looks like this:

[image]

I still can't find a solution to fix this. Please help! Thanks a lot.

Comment: What exactly is `R.drawable.none`?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It's just a 1x1 pixel image to do wordcap trick. Seems that something's wrong with the textview wrapping on Android L. Any suggestion?

Comment: @TuanNH what is WordCap?